# Search form in Revolution Slider - search criteria

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I am using the following to place a search form in a slider revolution hero slider. However it searches the entire site. I would like it to only search pages on my site. Any ideas what I need to change to make that work?

Comment: You are using any custom search form or default WordPress search.

Comment: a custom search form. 
Code:

<form role="search" method="get" id="" class="revtp-searchform" action="site name"><input type="text" value=""  name="s" placeholder="What are you looking for?" /><button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button></form>

Comment: Add a new HTML layer in hero slider and add this code

Comment: https://revolution.themepunch.com/wordpress-search-form-hero/

Comment: I have already added this on the slider, the issue is it display woocommerce products as well and i wish to display only the pages on my site

Comment: can you share your search function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this function

```
function wpshock_search_filter( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_search ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array('post','page') );
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpshock_search_filter');
```

OR you can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/

I hope its working for you.

Comment: should i add this function in the functions.php file?

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me. but if i can get exact match to the "words in search bar".

Comment: add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_make_search_exact', 10);
function my_make_search_exact($query){

    if(!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search) :
        $query->set('exact', true);
    endif;

}
Try this

Comment: Add this in fucntion

Comment: nahh.. this dint work, infact shows no result found for every other word i search for